# How to perform Multiple Condition check in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML with multiple attribute. I want to perform a condition check such that the element will be moved to desired location. I am not aware of the term or tags which can be use to achieve respective output.

XMl:

```
<Collection>

<Allparts>

    <part>
        <number>001</number>
        <material>Platinum</material>
        <price>High</price>
    </part>

    <part>
        <number>002</number>
        <material>Gold</material>
        <price>Medium</price>
    </part>

    <part>
        <number>003</number>
        <material>Silver</material>
        <price>Low</price>
    </part>


</Allparts>

<Allboms>

    <bom>
        <Part-number>001</Part-number>
    </bom>

    <bom>
        <Part-number>002</Part-number>
    </bom>

    <bom>
        <Part-number>003</Part-number>
    </bom>
</Allboms>

</Collection>
```

Needed Output:

```
<Collection>

<Allparts>

    <part>
        <number>001</number>
        <material>Platinum</material>
        <price>High</price>
    </part>

    <part>
        <number>002</number>
        <material>Gold</material>
        <price>Medium</price>
    </part>

    <part>
        <number>003</number>
        <material>Silver</material>
        <price>Low</price>
    </part>


</Allparts>

<Allboms>

    <bom>
        <Part-number>001</Part-number>
        <material>Platinum</material>
        <price>High</price>
    </bom>

    <bom>
        <Part-number>002</Part-number>
        <material>Gold</material>
        <price>Medium</price>
    </bom>

    <bom>
        <Part-number>003</Part-number>
        <material>Silver</material>
        <price>Low</price>
    </bom>
</Allboms>

</Collection>
```

The XML Which I Attempt :

```
<xsl:template match="bom">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose >
            <xsl:when test= "../../bom/Part-number=../../part/number" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "../../part/material" mode="move" />
            </xsl:when >
        </xsl:choose >
        <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />

    </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
```

Please suggest corrections:

Comment: You need to read up on `<xsl:key ...>` and the `key(...)` function, used to build a lookup table and search it.

Comment: Which XSLT version are you on? XSLT-1.0 or XSLT-2.0?

Comment: @LingamurthyCS I am using `<xsl:stylesheet version= "1.0"`

Comment: @JimGarrison As per your suggestion I reffere [http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp] But its sims like xml attribute.How can i apply this on my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below XSLT-1.0 solution should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:template match="Allboms/bom/Part-number">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Collection/Allparts/part[number = current()]/material | /Collection/Allparts/part[number = current()]/price"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity transform template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are two templates:

1. Identity transform template: it copes attributes and nodes as-is from the input document.
2. The template that match `Part-number`, which would copy itself and copy the respective `material` and `price` from `Allparts`.

**Using keys as suggested by @JimGarrison**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="material-by-num" match="/Collection/Allparts/part/material" use="../number"/>
    <xsl:key name="price-by-num" match="/Collection/Allparts/part/price" use="../number"/>

    <xsl:template match="Allboms/bom/Part-number">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('material-by-num', .) | key('price-by-num', .)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT uses two key declarations to match `material` and `price` using their sibling `number`'s value. The template for `Part-number` uses these keys to get the requried elements copied.